# How to trigger enter keypress of all textboxes in multiple sheets? - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

My workbook has three sheets(named Sheet1 ~ Sheet3) with TEXTBOXES.

This has a module.

```
Public dontDoThat As Boolean ' a public variable, visible throughout all your project you'll use to give way to synchronizing activity

Option Explicit

    Sub Synchronize(txt As String, shtName As String)
        dontDoThat = True ' set your public variable to True and prevent subsequent TextBox1_Change() events to run it again


        Dim sht As Variant
        For Each sht In Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
            If sht <> shtName Then Worksheets(sht).TextBox1.Text = txt

        Next

        dontDoThat = False ' set your public variable to False and allow subsequent TextBox1_Change() events to run it
    End Sub
```

These code can synchronize the TEXTBOX on all sheets.

But It's only for Text.

If I type some text in TEXTBOX1 of Sheet1, the same text will be display in TEXTBOX1 of all other sheets.

but The search function does not work on other sheets.

After I typed some text on TEXTBOX1 of Sheet1 and When I press the enter key, The search function works only in Sheet1.

**I want to trigger the enter keypress on Textboxes of all Sheets.**

**And these sheets also have TEXTBOX2.
Thus I want to know how to apply syncronization to TEXTBOX1 and TEXTBOX2 as well.**

I need someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Neo, I've done something like this before - where you create an autofilter either with Change event, or a specified KeyDown event (usually the Enter key - *vbKeyReturn*). Since you're using a KeyDown event, it wouldn't be overly exhaustive to use collections. You can, say, roll all of your TextBoxes in a collection either by name similarities, or by [TypeName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg278698(v%3Doffice.14)).

Specifically, for why I'm thinking you're having issues, perhaps loop through the Worksheets collection with an actual Worksheet object, and not a variant. And, since they're Worksheets objects, you can use *OLEObjects*.

```
Dim sht As WorkSheet
Dim x as Integer

x = 1    

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets
    Do Until sht.OLEObjects("TextBox & x") is Nothing
        If sht.Name <> shtName Then sht.OLEObjects("TextBox & x").Object.Text = txt
        x = x + 1
    Loop
Next
```

And even within that loop, you can do another loop to iterate over your multiple text boxes. Let us know how you want to proceed. Hope this helps...